# Direct sum of non-abelian groups doesn't satisfy the universal property of direct sum.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, direct-sum, universal-property, free-product

Let $C$ and $D$ be non-abelian groups. Show that $C\oplus D$ doesn't satisfy the universal property of direct sum.

I think I must assume that the universal property is true and then use the free product to define a homomorphism $f:C\oplus D\to C*D $, and then get a contradiction, but I don't know how to do this, or how to use that the groups $C$ and $D$ are not abelian.

Any help will be very appreciated! Thank you so much!

Comment: By the universal property of direct sum do you mean the universal property of a co-product in the category of groups?

Comment: Yes, I mean, I should assume that for every group G and morphisms $f_1: C\to G$, $f_2: D\to G$, there exists a unique morphism $g: C \oplus D \to G$ such that $g i_1 =f_1 $ and $g i_2 = f_2$, where  $i_1: C\to C\oplus D$ and $i_2: D\to C\oplus D$ are the canonical inclusions.

Comment: In $C \oplus D$ things commute so it is universal for those $f_i$ satisfying $f_1(c)f_2(d) = f_2(d)f_1(c)$ ?

Comment: $f_1 (c) f_2 (d)$ and $f_2(d) f_1 (c)$ are not the same since they are seen in the free product, and they're different words there. Also, $g(c+d)=g(c)g(d)=f_1 (c) f_2(d)$ and $g(d+c)=g(d)g(c)=f_2 (d) f_2(c)$, but $c+d=d+c$, so that would be a contradiction. Now, I'm honestly not seeing how am I using here the fact that $C$ and $D$ are not abelian, so it would be great if you could explain this to me.

Comment: It is not necessary for $C$ and $D$ to be nonabelian; they just have to be nontrivial.

Answer (score 1):

The assumption that $C$ and $D$ are nonabelian is a red herring; all that is needed is that they are nontrivial.  Indeed, let $c\in C$ and $d\in D$ be non-identity elements, and let $f:C\oplus D\to C*D$ be the canonical homomorphism that would be given by the universal property.  Then in $C*D$, $$cd=f(c,1)f(1,d)=f(c,d)=f(1,d)f(c,1)=dc.$$  This is a contradiction because $cd$ and $dc$ are distinct reduced words and thus are distinct elements of $C*D$ (here we use the assumption that $c$ and $d$ are not the identity to conclude that $cd$ and $dc$ are reduced).